# FFmpeg changes framerate to Variable when remuxing

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, mkv

I'm trying to change `.MKV` container to `.MP4` using FFmpeg without re-encoding video stream:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy output.mp4
```

The input file has Constant framerate:

```
Frame rate mode: Constant
Frame rate     : 30.000 fps
```

However, the output file got a variable framerate according to Mediainfo:

```
Frame rate mode       : Variable
Frame rate            : 30.000 fps
Minimum frame rate    : 29.412 fps
Maximum frame rate    : 30.303 fps
```

Total number of frames stays the same.
The output from ffmpeg:

```
Output #0, mp4, to 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 2560x1440 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 16k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:05:00.766000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 9023 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=  209201kB time=00:05:00.66 bitrate=5699.9kbits/s    
video:209045kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.074948%
```

Is it possible to set constant bitrate for the output? I've tried `-vsync` and `-r` but they seem to be ignored when `-c copy` is set.

Comment: There's no actual difference in frame timing (ignoring timebase resolution), so just chalk it up to a Mediainfo quirk.

Comment: See this in the ffmpeg bug tracker: "[Video copy from mkv to mp4 causes variable frame rate from constant frame rate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7927)"